# Getting 500 server error on login when hosted on IIS server locally

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, angular-cli-v6

I done with the asp.net-core api application at the back end and using angular-cli for the front end. Everything worked fine on localhost kestrel server or IIS express using Visual studio 2017 but on hosting on IIS locally, I do get the page loaded but its only problem when i try to login I get 500 server error but I dont get any information regarding error. It will be helpful if anybody tells me how to get it working on IIS

I tried to fix by changing some settings on the IIS server but I got no clue or fix.

Please download my source code and try running it https://github.com/abhilashlegend/DatingApp

I expect it to work as in the localhost server on the IIS

[image: error on iis server]

Comment: did you check response tab?

Comment: check the IIS Log and the eventlog on the machine, where IIS runs. Be prepared that your questions will be downvoted as it is poorly provided with code and examples what you tried

Comment: try to attach debugger to IIS process from Visual Studio, it will certainly stop at the exact line where an exception is thrown

Comment: if you are getting a general error message that `Internal Server Error` then turn on the CustomError in web config of API application

Comment: I checked the response tab but there is no data @Simonare

Comment: @FalcoAlexander I found out this to be some SQL error which i just saw from event log and it says: Cannot get a local application data path. Most probably a user profile is not loaded. If LocalDB is executed under IIS, make sure that profile loading is enabled for the current user.

Comment: so the problem is solved?

Comment: No @FalcoAlexander

Comment: I am actually getting a new error now: Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\datingapp'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'DatingAppLovSolDb'. [CLIENT: <local machine>]

Answer (score 3):

I fixed the problem go to SQL server management studio and under the database connection you find Security folder -> Logins. Right click and create new login IIS APPPOOL\datingapp
and under user Mapping select the database you want to grant access and select the database membership role db_datareader and db_datawriter and click ok. Restart sql server and iis server and fixed.

Answer (score 0):

From web.config, Just set stdoutLogEnabled="true" and check the aspnetcore log files. You should check the file where stdoutLogFile attribute points.

Comment: Where are the log files generated?

Comment: You can specify where the log files will be created but standart configuration is like below 

`<aspNetCore requestTimeout="00:07:00" processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" stdoutLogEnabled="false" **stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout"** />`

Comment: I am getting this error :Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\datingapp'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'DatingAppLovSolDb'. [CLIENT: <local machine>]